# self.tabBarController is NULL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I created a UITabBarController like the following and pushed a navigationController, but I now cannot set the title of tab bar items etc... as the tabbarcontroller is NULL.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        LoggedInFeedNavigationController *lvc = [[LoggedInFeedNavigationController alloc] initWithAccount:account];
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lvc]];
        [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
        [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
        [tabBarController release];
        [lvc release];
```

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: In LoggedInFeedNavigationController, self.tabBarController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for tabBarController I see the following

> If no tab bar is present **or the
>   receiver is a modal view**, this
>   property is nil.

In the comments it says that you are calling self.tabBarController from within the `LoggedInFeedNavigationController` and I would think it should work properly. But you are displaying the tab bar modally and if the documentation means even if it is inside of UITabBarController as a modal view then that is your problem.

Comment: What do you suggest to fix this problem?

Comment: If you absolutely need to access the tabBarController consider creating a property `@property(nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController *modalTabBarController;` inside your `LoggedInFeedNavigationController` and set that before you present it. I havent tested this so make sure it does not make a circular reference (put a breakpoint in the dealloc method). If so change it over to assign if you can guarantee that tabBarController will be alive as long as your controller.

Comment: Another method I would prefer would be to create a protocol and have the class creating the tab bar and `LIFNC` conform to it and manage the tabBarController it created appropriately from delegate callbacks.

Comment: I basically am creating a Modal loginViewController, and when the user logs in successfully, I will be getting rid of the old UINavController and replacing it with a UITabBarController with a UINavController inside

Comment: Would a delegate call back from the login controller not work to make all of the UI changes? ex. `[self.delegate loginController:self loggedIn:YES];` or similar then swap the UI on what ever implements the delegate.

Comment: I fixed it by passing the tabController from the viewController holding the navigationController to the viewController inside the navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your releasing your tab bar controller when you haven't finished with it. You want to initialize it once and release it only when your done with it like in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

Joe is completely right. This is also the case for custom segues as well. 
(Example: SWRevealViewController, etc)

This is what I did to get it to work based on Joe's answer and apples documentation.
In YourTabBarViewController.h file add the following:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController * myTabBarController;
```

Then in YourTabBarViewController.m file in viewDidLoad add the following:

```
self.myTabBarController = self;
self.myTabBarController.delegate = self;
```