# TabBarController returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller in storyboard as initial view controller

[image]

[image]

How does this return null

```
UITabBarController* tabbarController = (UITabBarController*) self.tabBarController;
NSLog(@"%@",tabbarController);
NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.tabBarController);
```

Originally what I am trying to do

```
NSMutableArray *newTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
NSLog(@"\n\n\n%lu\n\n\n",(unsigned long)[newTabs count]);
NSLog(@"self.tabBarController.viewControllers %@ \n\n",self.tabBarController);
[newTabs removeObjectAtIndex: 1];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newTabs];
```

Why am I getting null?

Comment: Where is this code? In what method is being called?

Comment: it is called in `XCTabViewController.m` 5 seconds after viewdidappear `[self performSelector:@selector(delayed) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];`

Comment: Then, wouldn't `self` be the UITabBarController ? Instead of `self.tabBarController`

Comment: Darn it, you are right. will accept the answer if you post one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason null is returned, is that `self` is your `UITabBarController`, therefore, it doesn't have anything on `self.tabBarController`

Your code should look like this:

```
NSMutableArray *newTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self viewControllers]];
NSLog(@"\n\n\n%lu\n\n\n",(unsigned long)[newTabs count]);
NSLog(@"self.viewControllers %@ \n\n",self);
[newTabs removeObjectAtIndex: 1];
[self setViewControllers:newTabs];
```

Comment: Good you found that. saved me

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift**

```
        let indexToRemove = 1
        if indexToRemove < (self.viewControllers?.count)! {
            var viewControllers = self.viewControllers
            viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)
            self.viewControllers = viewControllers
        }
```

directly use `self` in `UITabBarController` class, not `self.tabBarControllers`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Joe's Answer [self.tabBarController is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444666/self-tabbarcontroller-is-null)

If you have a navigation controller you need to add this to your YourTabBarViewController.h file

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController * myTabBarController;
```

Then in YourTabBarViewController.m file in viewDidLoad just assign it to self and add the delegate

```
self.myTabBarController = self;
self.myTabBarController.delegate = self;
```